# Component only gets updated when wrapped in a `div`

Tags: reactjs, components, react-hooks

I'm facing an issue where my component only gets updated when wrapped in a `div`.

I have a `switch statement` to render different versions of a child. It seems that everything works when I wrap my second case in a `div`, but if this `div` isn't present it doesn't work as expected. It seems that the `_getCurrentInputState` and `selectedBlock` don't update as they should.

```
const Parent= () => {

    {/* ... */}

    const _renderEditorPanel = () =>{
        const currentBlockType = blockList[selectedBlock].type
        switch(currentBlockType){
          case 'description': return (
            <EditorPanel 
              currentBlockType={'description'}
              selectedBlock={selectedBlock}
              _getBlock={_getBlock}
              _getCurrentInputState={_getCurrentInputState}
              _setCurrentInputState={_setCurrentInputState}
            />
          )
          case 'skills_and_requirements': return (
            <div>  {/* <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< This is needed to really update the child?
            */}
            <EditorPanel 
              currentBlockType={'skills_and_requirements'}
              selectedBlock={selectedBlock}
              _getBlock={_getBlock}
              _getCurrentInputState={_getCurrentInputState}
              _setCurrentInputState={_setCurrentInputState}
            />
            </div> {/* <<<< and this.*/}
          );
          default: return (
            <EditorPanel 
              currentBlockType={'default'}
              selectedBlock={selectedBlock}
              _getBlock={_getBlock}
              _getCurrentInputState={_getCurrentInputState}
              _setCurrentInputState={_setCurrentInputState}
            />
          );
      }
      }


      return (    
        <StyledJobEditor>
          {_renderEditorPanel()}    
          <div className="preview_panel">
            <div>
            <button onClick={
              () => setSelectedBlock("1")
            }>1</button>
            <button onClick={() => setSelectedBlock("2")}>2</button>
            <button onClick={() => setSelectedBlock("0")}>0</button>
            </div>

              {/*
                The sidebar will be an arraw of block. We should expect to use the .map function here.
              */}

          </div>
        </StyledJobEditor>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reason you're seeing this is that react has no way to tell that it should mount a new instance of the same component. By changing one to be wrapped in a `div` react sees that its different and remounts everything. Otherwise, it just treats it as a prop change.

Without seeing the implementation of `EditorPanel` I can't give anymore insight, but I'd guess that your unchanged props are only set once on mount or something similar.

Just like when mapping elements, you can provide a `key` to each element in the switch to inform react that each one is unique.

```js
switch (currentBlockType) {
  case 'description': return (
    <EditorPanel
      key="description"                 // Add this
      currentBlockType={'description'}
      selectedBlock={selectedBlock}
      _getBlock={_getBlock}
      _getCurrentInputState={_getCurrentInputState}
      _setCurrentInputState={_setCurrentInputState}
    />
  )
  case 'skills_and_requirements': return (
    <EditorPanel
      key="skills_and_requirements"      // Add this
      currentBlockType={'skills_and_requirements'}
      selectedBlock={selectedBlock}
      _getBlock={_getBlock}
      _getCurrentInputState={_getCurrentInputState}
      _setCurrentInputState={_setCurrentInputState}
    />
  )
  default: return (
    <EditorPanel
      key="default"                      // Add this
      currentBlockType={'default'}
      selectedBlock={selectedBlock}
      _getBlock={_getBlock}
      _getCurrentInputState={_getCurrentInputState}
      _setCurrentInputState={_setCurrentInputState}
    />
  )
```

Comment: This worked! I knew it had something to do with react only partially rendering my elements, but I could figure out how to force remounts everything. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah, basically react is seeing - last time I rendered a `EditorPanel` component, and this time I'm supposed to render one too, I'm going to assume they're the same one and reuse the instance of the first. By passing a key, you get more control over how react interprets rendering the same component. When you add the div, they don't match anymore so react doesn't think twice and mounts a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you don't need a switch case at all. Second, you are returning html, so it is a component and not a method, so start the method name with capital. You can reduce your code to

```
const RenderEditorPanel = () => {
        const currentBlockType = blockList[selectedBlock].type || 'default';
        return (
        <EditorPanel 
              currentBlockType={currentBlockType}
              selectedBlock={selectedBlock}
              _getBlock={_getBlock}
              _getCurrentInputState={_getCurrentInputState}
              _setCurrentInputState={_setCurrentInputState}
            />
        )
      }
```

Also when we use this component, it should be like below

```
<RenderEditorPanel />
```

Comment: Hi Nayan, thank you for the reply. Actually I'm returning JSX and the switch statement is needed because I will stack multiple cases over time and I prefer to use the switch statement so my code stays clean.